# ManyToManyField with two possible data types

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to get a ManyToManyField working with a `through` model, which would look something like this:

```
class DirectorCredit(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=False)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, null=True)
    tv_show = models.ForeignKey(TVShow, null=True)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I then want the `Movie` and `TVShow` models to be able to access these credits through a `ManyToManyField` (or a similar mechanism) like this:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    ....
    directors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='DirectorCredit')
    ....
```

(and the same with TVShow)

Is this sort of structure possible? Would `movieObject.directors.all()` fetch me all of the directors with `DirectorCredit` entries containing that movie? And would I be able to do the same thing with the `TVShow` model?

Comment: Interesting, I actually don't know what would happen. Why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but it is not great solution. The reason for that is that you can by mistake put both movie and tv show into one `DirectorCredit` object.

Consider making that relation using [gM2M](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/django-gm2m).